# Why mapStateToProps has Eslint warning 'Functions that return promises must be async'?

Tags: typescript, eslint, redux-form

I got Eslint warnings:

```
Functions that return promises must be async.
eslint(@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async)
```

On function:

```
import { getFormValues, change } from 'redux-form';

function mapStateToProps(state: any, ownProps: IWizardPageProps) {
    const stateProps = getFormValues('wizard')(state);
    return {
        ...ownProps,
        ...stateProps,
        change,
    };
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong. I don't see any promise there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redux-form itself relies on the promise call. So returning change or getFormValues will make it a promise returning functions.